# How to turn off denoising for certain objects? (UPBGE)

Tags: node-editor, game-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

Is it possible to have Viewport Denoising ON in the "Render Properties" panel, but have it OFF for certain objects? I heard this may be possible using layers but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can at runtime. Normally you could with enable/disable denoising per <kbd>Render Layer</kbd> or through manual <kbd>Compositing</kbd>.

Render Layers: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html

Compositing: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/denoise.html

Unfortunately UPBGE does not have any similar solution for run-time usage. At least not until the Blender developers implement their hinted `Real-Time Compositing Nodes`.

> Eevee
>
> ...
>
> A real-time compositing system is also planned, bringing compositing nodes > into the 3D viewport. The new Eevee will be designed to efficiently output > render passes and layers for interactive compositing, and other renderers > will be able to plug into this system too.

https://code.blender.org/2021/10/blender-3-x-roadmap/#Eevee